# landscape canonical management tool - create-distribution error

Tags: landscape

How to manage the repositories using landscape canonical management tool. when I used the GPG key to import the secret-key and Create the create distribution Ubuntu it shows error

```
# landscape-api create-distribution ubuntu

Got server error:
Status: 400
Error code: InvalidAction
Error message: The action CreateDistribution is not valid for this web service.
```

Comment: You can use the get-distributions command to verify if the 'ubuntu' distribution has been created already.